# ¿cómo puedo mostrar solamente los precios de un solo producto seleccionado q muestre solo los precios de diferentes productos?

Tags: php

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" id="precioV" name="precioV">
            <option value="A">Selecciona el precio</option>
            <?php 
            
            $sql="SELECT precio1,precio2,precio3
                    from articulos";
             $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
             while($precio = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)):
             ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $precio[0] ?>"><?php echo $precio[0] ?></option>
             <option value="<?php echo $precio[1] ?>"><?php echo $precio[1] ?></option>
             <option value="<?php echo $precio[2] ?>"><?php echo $precio[2] ?></option>
             <?php endwhile; ?>       
        </select>
```

la tabla es la siguiente :
create table articulos(
id_producto int auto_increment,
id_categoria int not null,
id_imagen int not null,
id_usuario int not null,
nombre varchar(50),
descripcion varchar(500),
cantidad int,
precio1 float,
precio2 float,
precio3 float,
fechaCaptura date,
primary key(id_producto)

```
                    );
```

Comment: Porque 1 producto tiene 3 precios diferentes? Quieres mostrar esos 3 precios hacia abajo en un select?

Comment: Siempre que veo nombres de columna del tipo: `columna1, columna2, columna3` me pregunto si no hay un grave error de diseño en ese modelo de datos. ¿Qué es lo que justifica eso? Por poner un ejemplo, si mañana hay un `precio4` ¿vas a meter mano de nuevo al modelo de datos, modificando la tabla para agregar una **nueva columna** llamada `precio4`?  Y, si el mes que viene hay un `precio5`, ¿de nuevo a meter mano al modelo de datos para agregar una **nueva columna**? Sea como sea, la pregunta tampoco se entiende y creo que todo viene de un error en el diseño.

Comment: Hay que seguir editando la pregunta para que sea entendible... puedes ayudarnos a redactarla de nuevo?

Comment: Bueno en realidad quisiera que el precio ya venga determinado al seleccionar un cliente lo estaba haciendo así fue algo que llegó a mi mente pero ahora lo estoy intentando cambiar